# Accessing data frame and printing custom error messages

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I have this dictionary having `Error_ID` and `Error_Messages` mapping, and these error messages have `{}` so that they can have dynamic data while printing

```
dict = {'101': 'Invalid table name {}', '102': 'Invalid pair {} and {}'}
```

I have this function which I'll call every time I have an error

```
def print_error(error_id,error_data)
        print(error_id,dict[error_id].format("sample_table") 

error_id='101'

print(error_id,dict[error_id].format("sample_table"))
Invalid table name sample_table
```

But for the second error what should I do so that I can have two things passed with the single print statement in my `print_error` module so that the output will be like

```
102 Invalid pair Sample_pair1 and Sample_pair2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's iterable unpacking feature to pass a variable number of arguments to `str.format`:

```
def print_error(error_id,error_data):
    if not isinstance(error_data, tuple): # if error_data isn't a tuple
        error_data= (error_data,) # make it a tuple so we can unpack it
    print(error_id,dict[error_id].format(*error_data)) # unpack the tuple

print_error('101',"sample_table")
print_error('102',('a','b'))
```